# Using ContinueWith with Multiple Tasks

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

This is not behaving quite as I thought it would the need is simple, launch a number of tasks to do operations on an object. One unique object per task. The second part is a `ContinueWith` when each task reports the results. However, I am not getting a `WhenAll` type behavior. Hopefully someone can set me straight.

```
_tasks = new Task<AnalysisResultArgs>[_beansList.Count];
for (int loopCnt = 0; loopCnt < _beansList.Count; loopCnt++)
{
    _tasks[loopCnt] = Task<AnalysisResultArgs>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        return _beansList[loopCnt].Analyze(newBeanData);
    });
    await _tasks[loopCnt].ContinueWith(ReportResults, 
                  TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously)  
    // do some housekeeping when all tasks are complete          
}

private void ReportResults(Task<AnalysisResultArgs> task)
{
     /* Do some serial operations
}
```

It was my understanding that `_beansList.Count` tasks would be launched and by using `await` on the `ContinueWith` the housekeeping work won't execute until all the Tasks have completed. I cannot block, as I need to be sure to be able to throttle the incoming data to prevent way too many tasks waiting to be executed.

Where did I goof, the await actually completes and the housekeeping gets run even though not ALL of the tasks have run to completion.

Comment: Please reduce to a minimal example that is complete and reproduces the problem. Side notes: If you use `Task.Run` instead of `StartNew`, and `await` instead of `ContinueWith`, then your code will be cleaner and behave better.

Comment: Stephen, I appreciate your comment and your recognized authority on this subject, however, that is a working minimal example, minus some of the additional classes. You statement about Task.Run rather than StartNew and using await (which I did) rather than ContinueWith, I will see if I can hunt the web for why that's better. I assumed that ContinueWith meant just that and await means just what it says. To paraphrase Start a new Task and when the task completes ContinueWith the second step. Await until all are frinish.

Comment: The example is not complete, though. I cannot paste it into a new project and observe its behavior in the debugger. I have blog posts on [why `StarNew` is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) and [why `ContinueWith` is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html).

Comment: @StephenCleary I have those blogs several times and they were a big help. No you cannot paste it into a project and step through. I apologize for that. Still your comments and thoers comments were a big help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not await all the tasks, you're awaiting the continuation in loops. You should use the `Task.WhenAll` method for this. Also, why do you need the continuation, if you can run it inside task? Simplify your code like this:

```
private void ReportResults(AnalysisResultArgs results)
{
     /* Do some serial operations */
}

...
_tasks = new Task<AnalysisResultArgs>[_beansList.Count];
for (int loopCnt = 0; loopCnt < _beansList.Count; loopCnt++)
{
    var count = loopCnt;
    _tasks[count] = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var results = _beansList[count].Analyze(newBeanData);
        ReportResults(results);
        return results;
    });
}

// do some housekeeping when all tasks are complete          
await Task.WhenAll(_tasks);
```

Comment: dang! You are absolutely correct. So simple and right in front of my nose. Thank you! Much appreciated.

Comment: @AeroClassics Good luck with your projects :)

Comment: there are two issues with the code,`results` need to be returned, else its a compilation error, since it is filled in the `Task<AnalysisResultArgs>[]` and  `loopCnt` shall be assigned to a local variable else it will lead to index put of range Exception at run time

Answer (score 1):

As @Stephen has already mentioned, the code in the question is not minimum, complete and verifiable. I have taken some liberty to make some assumptions and that's how in my view your code shall look like:

```
public async Task<AnalysisResultArgs[]> MainMethod()
{
    var _beansList = new List<AnalysisResultArgs>();

    for(int i=0; i< 99; i++) // Considering 100 records
        _beansList.Add(new AnalysisResultArgs());

    var _tasks = new Task<AnalysisResultArgs>[_beansList.Count];

    for (int loopCnt = 0; loopCnt < _beansList.Count; loopCnt++)
    {
        var local = loopCnt;
        _tasks[local] = Task.Run(async() => await ReportResults(_beansList[local].Analyze(new AnalysisResultArgs())));
    }

    return await Task.WhenAll(_tasks);
}

private async Task<AnalysisResultArgs> ReportResults(Task<AnalysisResultArgs> task)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return await Task.FromResult(new AnalysisResultArgs());
}

public class AnalysisResultArgs
{   
    public async Task<AnalysisResultArgs> Analyze(AnalysisResultArgs newBeanData)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return await Task.FromResult(new AnalysisResultArgs());
    }
}
```

**Assumptions / Other details:**

1. `Task.Delay` and `Task.FromResult` are the mere place holders of actual logic.
2. All methods in the call `Analyze` and `ReportResults` are Async
3. In the loop code could have been:

   ```
   _tasks[local] = ReportResults(_beansList[local].Analyze(new 
            AnalysisResultArgs()));
   ```

but if we are using `Task.Run` to start a `Task`, then `async, await` helps in freeing up the calling thread pool thread / synchronization context. It helps in improving the system scalability.

4. Assumed `_beansList` is of type `List<AnalysisResultArgs>`, but that can be modified based on actual requirement
5. `ReportResults` could be modified to take a `Func<Task<AnalysisResultArgs>> func`, instead of simple d`Task<AnalysisResultArgs>`, thus doing `await func()` inside the method and then the calling code could have been truly async as follows:

   ```
     _tasks[local] = Task.Run(async() => await ReportResults(async() => await 
     _beansList[local].Analyze(new AnalysisResultArgs())));
   ```